# how to deduce return type from lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

here is the sample code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T foo(T(*fp)())
{
    return fp();
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<<foo([]->int{ return 1; });
}
```

when I compiled the code above, compiler says it cannot deduce the template argument,
but I have specified the return type of lambda.

Comment: Have you tried adding `+` before `[]` (making explicit the conversion lambda -> function pointer)?

Comment: I see another problem, with g++ and clang++: the explicit return type. Should be requested the explicit use of  `()` before `->int`; so `foo(+[]()->int{ return 1; });`. Otherwise, you can avoid the explicit return type (it's deduced from `return 1;`), so `foo(+[]{ return 1; });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foo` takes function pointer while you're passing a lambda, but implicit conversion (from lambda to function pointer) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) for `T`, which makes the invocation failing.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can specify template argument explicitly:

```
foo<int>([]()->int{ return 1; });
// ^^^^^
```

Or convert lambda to function pointer by `operator+` or `static_cast`.

```
foo(+[]()->int{ return 1; });
//  ^
foo(static_cast<int(*)()>([]()->int{ return 1; }));
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^
```

BTW: Omitted parameter list used with trailing return type is a C++23 [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) feature. (So I added `()`s.) And as @max66 suggested without trailing return type the lambda works fine too; the return type would be deduced automatically, such as `foo(+[]{ return 1; });`.

Comment: For your code, clang-cl gives: *error : lambda requires '()' before return type*. Is dropping the `()` (after `[]`) a C++20 thing? MSVC gives a similar error message.

Comment: @AdrianMole - Same error from g++, compiling C++17 (and I'm surprised: I didn't know this requirement).

Comment: Yep, if you build with GCC11, the error message is "parameter declaration before lambda trailing return type only optional with '-std=c++2b' or '-std=gnu++2b'"

Comment: Clang-cl set to using the C++20 gives the same error message. As does MSVC set to use "latest" (C++23??)

Comment: @AdrianMole max66 Yes it's a C++23 [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) feature. *Omitted parameter list: function takes no arguments, as if the parameter list were (). This form can only be used if none of constexpr, consteval, mutable, exception specification, attributes, or trailing return type is used. (until C++23)*

Comment: Well, as we're still in 2021, maybe you should add the required `()` to your code samples?

Comment: @AdrianMole Fine enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the call site, you can always just change `foo` so it can take a lambda:

```
template<typename F>
std::invoke_result_t<F> foo(F&& f)
{
    return f();
}
```

Note also that your lambda currently works only with C++23 - add the (empty) parameter list if you want this to work everywhere:

```
[]()->int{ return 1; }
```